# Batching sending events to event hub using EventHubClient

Tags: azure-eventhub

Can someone guide me to an reference implementation where the events are being sent to event hub using the batch mode. ?

Thanks
Shrini

Comment: Which language and SDK are you coding with?

Comment: Hello, if the answer is helpful, could you please [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top)? It would be helpful for others who have the same problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you're using Java, the key code should looks like below:

```
       public static void main(String[] args)
                 throws EventHubException, IOException {

    final ConnectionStringBuilder connStr = new ConnectionStringBuilder()
            .setNamespaceName("----ServiceBusNamespaceName-----") // to target National clouds - use .setEndpoint(URI)
            .setEventHubName("----EventHubName-----")
            .setSasKeyName("-----SharedAccessSignatureKeyName-----")
            .setSasKey("---SharedAccessSignatureKey----");

    final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4);
    final EventHubClient sender = EventHubClient.createFromConnectionStringSync(connStr.toString(), executorService);

    try {
        for (int batchNumber = 0; batchNumber < 10; batchNumber++) {
            final EventDataBatch events = sender.createBatch();
            EventData sendEvent;

            // This do..while loop demonstrates - Maximizing batch size for every send call.
            // sending multiple EventData's in one batch - guarantees order among the events sent in this batch
            // and provides transactional semantics for the batch (all-or-none)

            do {
                final PayloadEvent payload = new PayloadEvent(100 + batchNumber);
                final byte[] payloadBytes = gson.toJson(payload).getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());

                sendEvent = EventData.create(payloadBytes);
                sendEvent.getProperties().put("from", "javaClient");
            } while(events.tryAdd(sendEvent));

            sender.sendSync(events);
            System.out.println(String.format("Sent Batch - Batch Id: %s, Size: %s", batchNumber, events.getSize()));
        }

    } finally {
        sender.closeSync();
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}
```

The completed sample code of batching send for java is [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs/blob/master/samples/Java/Basic/SendBatch/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/eventhubs/samples/sendbatch/SendBatch.java).